# The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.7.2

I tried to extract ZIP made by 7z (using Deflate), and my application threw me:
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.InvalidDataException: The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.

However, the files still get extracted.
How may I suppress this message?

Comment: You can't "suppress" exceptions. When that exception is thrown, inflation either failed partially or completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, I solved my own problem.
Always use the Windows Explorer's Send to compressed (zipped) folder to zip files to be used with .NET's zip extraction.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I press here" - "Have you tried to stop pressing?"